# How to add root route pointing to a page in Ruby on Rails 5 with Ancestry Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5, ancestry

I'm using the Ancestry Gem for my project. How do I set the `root` path to one of the Ancestry paths?

My page named `home` looks like this: `http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/15`. It's ideal to have `http://127.0.0.1:3000/pages/home` and not the home id, but that's the next challenge.

I started with:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # resources :pages
  ...
  root 'pages#index', as: 'pages_index'
  ...
end
```

And of course it showed me the list of pages, but I would like to target the page named home, or in this case id 15. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `defaults`:

```
root 'pages#show', defaults: { id: 15 }
```